# Bootstrap modal stops after several clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I link to a bootstrap modal as shown below; however, after one round of open/close the modal stops responding to clicks. I have tried to replacing the code with the example from bootstrap documentation and it works. I'm unsure where to begin debugging.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="campaign-slider-content" tabindex="-1"  aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height:100%;"> 
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"> 
            </div> 
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag(campaign.featured_image.url(:crowdreview_cropped), width: '288') 
campaign_slider_detail_path(campaign.id), data: { toggle: 'modal', target: '#campaign-slider-content'}%>
```

Comment: where is the html button or link to open the modal? Dont see how the code you presented is an issue. http://jsfiddle.net/qcvoofap/

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing the modal properly. You need to change:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="#campaign-slider-content" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
```

to:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
```

Comment: I tried that; however, it does not help nor change functionality.